# Where is the Git repo physically located in the file system?

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 RC. I added a project to source control using Git. The `Default Repository Location` in the Global Settings is set to `D:\Git`. I committed the files, but there is nothing in the `D:\Git` folder. So where is the repo being saved to? I don't think it's going to GitHub or Team Services, because I never set that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be in a hidden folder (.git) wherever your code is stored

Answer (score 0):

Your Git repository is stored in a folder ending in `.git`.  It is possible that this folder is not showing up in `D:\Git` on your Windows explorer because it is a system folder.  Try searching on `D:` for `*.git` and you should find it.

Answer (score 0):

In a command prompt, go into your git working files (not the repo itself but the cloned directory where you work is (e.g. c:\mywork).

Type in `git config --get remote.origin.url`

This will tell you where your origin is (where your clone came from). If your location is indeed `D:\Git` this will confirm it.

As other mentioned, you probably did not see the hidden folder (.git).